# How to resolve and issue on training GMM -HMM for speech recognition?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, gmm

I am working on coice recognition study , i converted a voice data set to LSF (line spectrale frequency)  by decoding file coded by amr-wb (G722.2) , i build a dataset with files of 16 vectors  of ISF/LSF at each frame  .

i used a python code well running for MFCC features for the same dataset in wav format ; but with the data set converted to LSf vectors i got the message when we start trainging and fit the GMMmmm model .

the error message :

base.py", line 469, in _do_forward_pass
    return logsumexp(fwdlattice[-1]), fwdlattice

IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: Probably some of your feature files is empty, that is why size is 0

Comment: ok i will check